# Java shifting a 2D array to the right, with last column being placed in first

Tags: java, algorithm, multidimensional-array

Hi I was wondering if I could get help creating a method to shift a java 2D array to the right

```
public void filter(PixelImage pi) {
    Pixel[][] data = pi.getData();  // get image data

    for (int row = 0; row < pi.getHeight(); row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col <  pi.getWidth(); col++) {
               if(col == pi.getWidth()-1){
                   Pixel lastCol = data[row][pi.getWidth()-1];
                   data[row][0] = lastCol;
                }
               else{    
                Pixel temp1 = data[row][col];              
                data[row][col+1] = temp1;
            }
        }
    }  
    // reset data into the PixelImage object pi
    pi.setData(data);
}
```

Here is my code sample that is not working properly, could someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Have **YOU** tried debugging yet? What where your findings?

Comment: Please add a small example, the desired result and the actual 'wrong' result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this might be work.

```
public void filter(PixelImage pi) {
    Pixel[][] data = pi.getData();  // get image data

    for (int row = 0; row < pi.getHeight(); row++) {
        Pixel lastCol = data[row][pi.getWidth()-1];
        for (int col = pi.getWidth() - 1; col > 0; col--) {          
                data[row][col] = data[row][col-1];
            }
        data[row][0] = lastCol;
    }  
    // reset data into the PixelImage object pi
    pi.setData(data);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, did't notice that answer similar to mine exists and edited it a bit

Comment: @MBo Excuse me bro, when i post my answer didn't saw yours. please bring back your answer and i delete this.

Comment: No, your answer was some moments earlier :) and contains the same information. It completely solves author's problem.

Answer (score 0):

To shift Right you should start shifting from right side.
Now what you are doing is like:

```
A  B  C  D  E
A->A  C  D  E
A  A->A  D  E
A  A  A->A  E
A  A  A  A->A
```

But you should do it like:

```
A  B  C  D  E
A  B  C  D  E->temp
A  B  C  D->D
A  B  C->C  D
A  B->B  C  D
A->A  B  C  D
temp->E A B C D
```

For that you need to start you loop from `length-1` to `0`

Answer (score 0):

This will work kindly check

> call method *shiftByOnePlace* number of times you need to shift

```
/**
 * 
 * @param matrix
 * @param noOfShift
 */
public static void shiftByOnePlace(int[][] matrix) {
        // shifting all rows to right by 1 place
        for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
            int[] js = matrix[i];
            int temp = js[js.length - 1];
            shift(js);
            js[0] = temp;
    }
}

public static  void shift(int[] a) {
    for(int i=a.length-2;i>=0;i--) {
        a[i+1]= a[i];
    }
}
```